# É possível inserir parâmetros nos filters attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, atributos

Utilizo ASP.NET e para fazer o controle de acesso por nível, utilizo um filtro que verifica o nível de permissão do usuário e permite o acesso a *view*.

```
[HttpPost]
[AutorizacaoFilterAttribute] //Esse filtro analisa a permissão do usuário
public ActionResult GetEmailAnalisysData()
{

}
```

Porém dentro do Filtro e preciso fazer um `switch` **para cada** *view* que eu adicionar o `[AutorizacaoFilterAttribute]` e isso acaba sendo cansativo, fora que eu vou esquecer de adicionar em um ou outro.

A pergunta é: É possível passar parâmetros pelo *filter*? exemplo:

```
[HttpPost]
[AutorizacaoFilterAttribute(1)] //1 significa o nível necessário para esse filter, assim eu me livro de precisar fazer um switch comparando o nome de cada view
public ActionResult GetEmailAnalisysData()
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesse seu pode fazer como quiser, mas se for usar o [`AuthorizationFilterAttribute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh834134(v=vs.118)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é o padrão do *framework*, aí não tem como colocar argumentos.

Você pode criar o seu herdando o `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`, aí pode acrescer um construtor com o parâmetro que deseja. Mas o *framework* não respeitará isso, será necessário criar a lógica de controle, talvez criando um `Controller` próprio também. Inclusive porque esse nível teria que ser enviado de alguma forma para comparar com esse argumento. Não sei como faz sem o atributo.

Outra possibilidade é ter ações diferentes para cada nível.

Comment: Eu solucionei utilizando a herança do `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`, adicionei uma variável chamada Level e agora consigo passar esse valor em especifico em cada View: `     [AutorizacaoFilterAttribute(Level = 10)] ` . Obrigado;

Comment: Então você herdou como eu falei?

Comment: Sim ! agora ao invés de utilizar um amontoado de variáveis que recebia o nome da View e como valor o nível necessário, eu apenas insiro a anotação do filtro em cima da mesma passando o nível dela, dentro do filtro eu verifico: NívelUser >= Level(que foi passado via atributo),se for ele permite, senão ele manda para a pagina de login. Fez eu economizar umas 20 linhas(pois eu fazia o case para cada View do meu site).